# Creating secret keys with same shared secret leads to different results

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, secret-key

i'm working on Android application which requires to create secure channel between the app and the server(.NET), the first step is we creating shared secret, the app generates key pair (EC) and sends the public key to the server, then the server creates its own key pair and send the public key to the app and save the shared secret created based on app's public and server private keys and the server send back to the app its own public, salt and iv, then the app perform key agreement, the result is that both the android app and the server have string created based on public-private keys.

Later when the android app want to send some encrypted message to the server, i take the generated secret, salt and iv and creates secret key to be able use `Cipher` to encrypt the message.

The problem is even though the app and the server have exact the same shred secret, salt and iv for some reason android generates different `SecretKey` than the server (we checked in debug mode to see that the shared secret salt and iv are same).

Here is the code i use to create secret key:

```
byte[] sharedSecretBytes = Base64.decode(sharedSecretBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] ivBytes = Base64.decode(ivBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] saltBytes = Base64.decode(saltBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);


String sharedSecret = new String(sharedSecretBytes, "UTF-8");
//i tried to use different encoding, no luck.
//String sharedSecretAscii = new String(sharedSecretBytes, "ASCII");
char[] charArray  = sharedSecret .toCharArray();

PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(charArray, saltBytes, 1000, 256);
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
SecretKey key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

//here the keyBytes are not the same as generated in the server.
byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();

//i saw in some tutorial somene do this, not sure why because we can provide the key as is to the cipher, 
//the problem is that both not working.
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");


IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(logNumber.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String asString = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

I also made try to pub hard-coded shared secret as "123abc" in both android and server side and actually it worked so my only guess is that the problem coming from converting the `sharedSecrte.toCharArray()`, if the sharedSecret contains weird characters can lead java generating bad secret key?

Also we working on iOS app that make exactly same process and have no issue to generate correct keys.

Comment: Placing binary data in a String `sharedSecret` and then convert it to characters is indeed a very bad idea. Strings/characters are designed to contain printable characters, not binary data. I assume therefore that this is your main problem.

Comment: @Robert after hours of research didn't found any solution with the native `java.security` classes. I used  `bouncycastle` libraries and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the only thing that worked as expected was to use Bouncy Castle library
What i done is :

```
PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
      generator.init(sharedSecretBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
      byte[] dk = ((KeyParameter) generator.generateDerivedParameters(256)).getKey();
      SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(dk, "AES");


      IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(logNumber.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Still don't understand why native java.security makes trouble .